# Trying to show images stored in the device but it's very slow. I read showing thumbnails is a better way to do this. How can I generate thumbnails?

Tags: flutter

Flutter - Instagram like image picker tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfA3koMnhvM&t=527s

I am following this video. In the comments section, the poster says Note: while implementing this to make sure to use an image package to generate thumbnail. And show the thumbnail instead of the image. It will prevent the Flutter bug of not handling a large image cache.

I checked the [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package and did this.

```
Image image = decodeImage(File('test.webp').readAsBytesSync());

Image thumbnail = copyResize(image, width: 120);
```

Now how can I show this thumbnail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can just specify the cacheHeight or cacheWidth now to make a lower resolution copy

Answer (score 0):

Thumbnail is just a picture with a lower resolution. You just need to replace your image with the thumbnail of that image.
You can generate a thumbnail for your image online like from this site: [GENERATE THUMBNAILS](http://makethumbnails.com/#dropzone)
You will have to store them as well to read so it's not an optimal solution.